# What is a solderometer?

Tags: identify-a-tool

I have this tool and not sure what it is used for. The T-handle, if you will, swivels. The word “Waterbury” is stamped on one side. And “solderometer” is stamped on the other side. I googled it with no helpful results. I would [image]

Comment: Please [edit] to complete your question, which appears to be cut off mid-sentence.

Answer (score 2):

I found several references in Google Books from the early 1900s to a solderometer as a tool that's used to measure the percentage of tin in a batch of molten solder. Apparently, solder with less than 35% tin would make a no-good porous solder.

The books' mentions of a solderometer were in reference to making splices in heavy electrical cables, especially during the transition from DC to AC power distribution. "Cable wipes and lugs" were mentioned, and there was a Waterbury Cable Company.

Comment: Thank you for your troubles. Much appreciated. I guess my research skills need some improvement. Thanks again!

Comment: Fascinating.  [This](https://www.edaboard.com/blog/how-to-calculate-the-tin-lead-content-of-any-solder-using-only-a-weight-scale.1974/) explains how to do it without this tool.  You are basically measuring density.  Presumably this device has a density somewhere between tin and lead, and sinks into a pot of molten solder just the right amount if the mix is what it's meant to be.